# Distribution of Quantifiers over Operators

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I was looking at this website   https://nokyotsu.com/qscripts/2014/07/distribution-of-quantifiers-over-logic-connectives.html
 and was surprised to find out that quantifiers could be written in this form. Does anyone know what the if then statement written backwards refers to here? Also, if someone has any good resources that proves these statements for a beginner in logic referring to quantifiers like these, that would be really helpful. I am curious to learn.

Comment: Do you mean the note at the bottom?

Comment: Check out propositional logic truth tables --- if you can learn the basic rules, you can treat the results on the website as exercises to prove yourself. It's a great way to get started!

Comment: @BillWallis The asker seems to be asking about quantifiers, and in which cases we use particular connectives, etc.

Comment: @amWhy I know, and my comment was off topic in that respect. However, I know that I found propositions with quantifiers easier to work with after practising things on truth tables.

Comment: Written in what form? Everything on that website looks very standard to me.

Comment: How do you use quantifiers with truth tables?

Comment: I already understand the logic truth tables. I have never seen a backwards if then statement. Does that even relate to quantifiers though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the $\leftarrow$ means that the right side implies the left side. Or, as a logical operator, it would be an 'if .. then ..', but with the right side as the 'if', and the left side as the 'then'. So, for example, $P \leftarrow Q$ would be the same as $Q \rightarrow P$

Second, to understand these equivalences (and why some of these only go one way), notice that an existential can be seen as kind of disjunction, that is, if $a,b,c,...$ denote the objects in your domain, then you can think of an existential like this:

$\exists x \: \varphi(x) \approx \varphi(a) \lor \varphi(b) \lor \varphi(c) \lor ...$

I use $\approx$ since this is technically *not* a logical equivalence, but if you really want to prove the above equivalence, you'd need to go into formal semantics, and that might be a bit to much to ask for a binner in logic. But, what you would be doing there *does* follow this basic idea, so let's just leave it more informal.

So, with this 'equivalence', we can show (or at least informally understand) an equivalence like $\exists x \: (P(x) \lor Q(x)) \Leftrightarrow \exists x P(x) \lor \exists x Q(x)$ as follows:

$\exists x (P(x) \lor Q(x)) \approx$

$(P(a) \lor Q(a)) \lor (P(b) \lor Q(b)) \lor (P(c) \lor Q(c)) \lor ... \Leftrightarrow$ (by Association and Commutation we can reorder)

$(P(a) \lor P(b) \lor P(c) ...) \lor (Q(a) \lor Q(b) \lor Q(c) ...) \approx$

$\exists x P(x) \lor \exists x Q(x)$

By thinking of a universal as a kind of conjunction over all objects over the domain, i.e using

$\forall x \: \varphi(x) \approx \varphi(a) \land \varphi(b) \land \varphi(c) \land ...$

you can likewise show that:

$\forall x \: (P(x) \land Q(x)) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \: P(x) \land \forall x \: Q(x)$ (good exercise to do for yourself!)

Comment: Would you know a good resource as well that goes into formal semantics regarding these quantifiers? I do understand some semantics.