# Why is this a prenex form of that formula?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic

This fact is used in the proof of the Theorem on Functional Extensions in J.R. Shoenfield's *Mathematical Logic*.

Let $x, y_1, ..., y_n$ be distinct variables, $A$ - some formula in which no variable  other than $x, y_1, ...,  y_n$ is free, $B$ -  some closed formula, and $f$ - a new $n$-ary functional symbol.

> If $C$ is a prenex form of  $A\to B$, then $\exists y_1...\exists y_nC_x[fy_1...y_n]$ is a prenex form of $\forall y_1...\forall y_n A_x[fy_1...y_n]\to B$.

The way it is mentioned in the proof makes me feel like this should be trivial but I still can't see why the statement is true.

P.S. I think I provided enough details to prove the statement but I am not sure. I will provide the whole proof if necessary.

**Edit:** In the book $B$ is a prenex form of $A$ iff $B$ is in prenex form and $A$ can be converted to $B$ by using only prenex operations:

1) Replace a part $\exists x C$ by $\exists yC_x[y]$, provided $y$ is not free in $C$.

2) Replace a part $\neg \exists xC$ by $\forall x\neg C$ or $\neg \forall xC$ by $\exists x\neg C$

3) Replace a part $\exists x C\vee D$ by $\exists x (C\vee D)$ or $\forall x C\vee D$ by $\forall x(C\vee D)$, provided $x$ is not free in $D$

4) Replace a part $C\vee \exists x D$ by $\exists x (C\vee D)$ or $C\vee \forall x D$ by $\forall x(C\vee D)$, provided $x$ is not free in $C$.

Comment: Also see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235527/distribution-of-quantifiers-over-operators for an intuitive explanation why $\exists y \ C \lor D$ is equivalent to $\exists y (C \lor D)$ provided $y$ is not free in $D$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it is a simple relabeling of the first formula. ($\forall y_1...y_n A[y_1...y_n])\rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\exists y_1...y_n A[y_1...y_n]\lor B$. Then we can choose a C such that $C[y_1...y_n]:=A[y_1...y_n]\lor B$, and rewrite the original statement as $\exists y_1...y_n C[y_1...y_n]$, where $A[y_1...y_n]\lor B=C[y_1...y_n]$

Comment: @user400188 Yes! I think I understand now. Although you've probably meant to write $\exists y_1...\exists y_n (\neg A_x[fy_1...y_n]\vee B)$. Also, we have to make sure that we can work with $A_x[fy_1...y_n]\to B$ the same way as with $A\to B$; so $B$ should be modified using the first operation so that it contains none of the $y_1, ..., y_n$.