# Quantifiable logic. Difference between $\forall y, \forall z(F(y,z) \implies Q(y)) $ and $\forall y, \exists z (F(y,z)\implies Q(y))$.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, quantifiers

I'm reading "how to prove it" and am struggling on the following question:

"Analyse the logical form: If anyone in the dorm has the measles, then everyone who has a friend in the dorm will have to be quarantined".

I came up with the following:

$\exists x(D(x) \land M(x))\implies \forall y ,\forall z ((F(y,z) \land D(z)) \implies Q(y))$

Where $D(x) = $ x is in the dorm, $M(x)=$ x has the measles, $F(y,z)=$ y is a friend of z, $Q(x)=$ x has to quarantine.

I looked up the answer online, and my answer is correct, except instead of $\forall z$ it is $\exists z$. I can't seem to work this out. Surely for all combinations of people y and z, if they are friends (ie: $F(y,z)$) then my statement/solution is correct.

Can somebody explain to me why we would use $\exists z$ instead of $\forall z$ in this case?

Comment: My answer would be something like $\ldots\implies \forall y (\exists z(F(y,z)\wedge D(z))\implies Q(y))$. Please check the parenthesis on the solution you found. Anyways, by a prenex normal form convertion (which I still do not have intuition on it... help huhu), my answer should be equivalent to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you overlooked a difference in parentheses.

Your answer is

$$\forall y \forall z ((F(y,z) \land D(z)) \implies Q(y)),$$

and I'm guessing the answer in the book is

$$\forall y (\exists z (F(y,z) \land D(z)) \implies Q(y)).$$

Both of these sentences are equivalent, so both of them are correct. I like the second sentence better, since the phrase "who has a friend" sounds like existential quantification inside of the antecedent of an implication. But the first one is correct too.

On the other hand, the sentence

$$\forall y \exists z ((F(y,z) \land D(z)) \implies Q(y))$$

is completely different. This sentence says that for every person $y$, there is another person ($z$) who

- is not a friend of $y$, or
- does not live in the dorm, or
- will have to be quarantined.

If the answer key really does have the third sentence here, then that's probably a printing error.

---

By the way, here's how to show that the first two sentences are equivalent. We start with the sentence

$$\forall y \forall z ((F(y,z) \land D(z)) \implies Q(y)).$$

First, we rewrite the implication as disjunction:

$$\forall y \forall z (\neg (F(y,z) \land D(z)) \lor Q(y)).$$

Disjunction factors out of universal quantification:

$$\forall y (\forall z \ \neg (F(y,z) \land D(z)) \lor Q(y)).$$

De Morgan's law for quantifiers:

$$\forall y (\neg \exists z (F(y,z) \land D(z)) \lor Q(y)).$$

Finally, rewrite the disjunction as implication again:

$$\forall y (\exists z (F(y,z) \land D(z)) \implies Q(y)).$$

Comment: This makes sense. Can I ask (maybe I will get to this later in the book), how can you show that those first two sentences are equivalent? I understand it intuitively,  but it would be interesting to be able to prove this (although as I say, maybe I will get on to this later in the book).

Comment: Certainly. I've added that derivation to my answer. (I might have to add more justification to my "universal quantification commutes with disjunction" step; I'll have to think about that one.)

Comment: @TannerSwett The universal does *not* commute with disjunction in general ... but it works in this case, because $Q(y)$ does not contain any free variable $z$. So, what you really need here is one of the general [Prenex Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form), namely the one that says that where $x$ is not a free variable in formula $\psi$, we have that $\forall x (\phi \lor \psi)$ is equivalent to $\forall x \ \phi \lor \psi$

Comment: @Bram28 Yup. I've changed the description to "disfunction factors out of universal quantification," since it's analogous to how a constant can be factored out of a summation. I still suspect that maybe I should give a better explanation, if only I could think of one.

Comment: @TannerSwett Well, you can't reduce many of the Prenex Laws to more basic equivalence laws ... and this is one of these. So, if you want to explain this Prenex Law, you'll have to bring up semantics ... or go through a fairly painful formal proof .

Comment: Well, it's not horribly hard to prove. We want to prove that if $\forall x (Q \lor P(x))$ (where $x$ does not appear in $Q$), then $Q \lor \forall x P(x)$. We will prove the contrapositive. Assume that $\neg Q \land \exists x \neg P(x)$. Since we have $\exists x \neg P(x)$, we can instantiate and conclude $\neg P(a)$. We then have $\neg Q \land \neg P(a)$. From here, existential generalization allows us to conclude that $\exists x (\neg Q \land \neg P(x))$. This is the negation of the original premise, so the proof by contrapositive is complete.

Comment: @TannerSwett Right ... though for showing equivalence you  also need to go the other way.  And the thing is, in the end, even when you have the whole formal proof of their equivalence, it really doesn't make things any more *intuitive*. So, one thing (though it's really a bit cheating) is to do something like I do in this post:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235527/distribution-of-quantifiers-over-operators

Comment: Yup. But hopefully it's not too unintuitive that the statement "For every student, either it snowed last night or that student is going to school" is logically equivalent to the statement "Either it snowed last night, or every student is going to school." That said, now that I think of it, it's much *more* intuitive that the sentence "Every student is, if it didn't snow last night, going to school" is equivalent to the sentence "If it didn't shoe last night, every student is going to school."

Comment: So, if I had time tonight, I'd edit this answer to give a different proof. That proof would proceed by taking the contrapositive of the implication in the sentence, then factoring the antecedent out of the quantification, then taking the contrapositive again, and finally then applying De Morgan's law for quantifiers.